# How can I fetch data in API without giving this error

Tags: json, flutter, api

I want to retrieve some data in API, but that's giving an error . How can i get List of all posts

This is my DataModel class:

```
class DataModel {
    DataModel({
        required this.id,
        required this.title,
        required this.body,
    });

    int id;
    String title;
    String body;

    factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataModel(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
    };
}
```

And this is my get future data function:

```
Future<DataModel?> getData(context) async {
  DataModel? result;
  try {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("https://someapi.com/posts"),); // this is example api for security
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      result = DataModel.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("error");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  }
  return result;
}
```

That's giving me an error like that:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Comment: Do you mind adding a sample of your raw data to the question. Im guessing this has something to do with your fromJson method

Answer (score 0):

I think in the reponse you are getting a list of items which has to be used like the following

```dart
var list = json.decode(response.body);
List<DataModel> result = list.map((i) => DataModel.fromJSON(i)).toList();
return result;
```

And the method will return

```
Future<List<DataModel>>?
```